# Как определить какому юзеру принадлежит число?

Tags: javascript

имеется объект `chanels`

```
{
   chanelId: 1,
   rangeIn: 1,
   rangeOut: 99
},
{
   chanelId: 2,
   rangeIn: 100,
   rangeOut: 200
}
```

Как можно узнать какому `chanelId` принадлежит заданное число?
Например что-то типа:

```
getRange(chanels, 3) // число 3 принадлежит chanelId 1
```

Comment: У вас, видимо, допущена опечатка в range

Comment: @reznikovkg спасибо, исправил

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
function getRange(chanels, range) {
    const t = chanels.find(function (item) { 
        return item.rangeIn <= range && item.rangeOut >= range
    })
    return t ? t.chanelId : -1 // -1 - not found
}
```

Comment: Точнее будет >= и <= в вашем случае. Иначе границы не попадут

Comment: При проверке на коде из вопроса нужно учитывать, что в `rageOut` там опечатка.

Comment: Точно! Поправил!